# SQL - How to set a variable in a CTE in Snowflake ? and use that variable in CTE

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

SET A = 'Y';
above my CTE

I'm getting below error
Error: invalid identifier 'A'

---

Comment: This isn't specific to Snowflake. Generally you can define a CTE with the named value then refer to it via a cross join. `with vars as (select 'Y' as A) select * from Table T cross join vars...`

Comment: Can you provide the body of the CTE? Or perhaps all the code?

Comment: If i have a nested CTE like below, sorry, unfortunately i cant paste the code, where should i declare the variable, at the top?

WITH A AS
(
),
LIST AS 
(
),
LOCAL AS
(
)
SELECT *
FROM ....

Comment: @Ria variables and CTEs are not equivalent or interchangeable.

Answer (score 1):

Your question isn't very clear, but you can make reference to a variable in a CTE in the same way you do in any `select` statement:

```
set a = 'Y';

with x as (
select $a as var
)
select var
from x;
```

or if you want to do it in a single query.  This example shows a bunch of unnecessary cte levels, but illustrates the point.

```
with a as (
    select 'Y' as var
), x as (
    select var from a
)
select var
from x;
```